# AWS CodePipeline - How to create a change set cross account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I would like to in an account A run a codepipeline that create a changeset for a stack in account B.
Is there a way to do that?

Obs.: A and B are under the same root account

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can find instructions on how to use resources from a different account in [Create a Pipeline in AWS CodePipeline That Uses Resources from Another AWS Account](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/how-to-create-pipeline-cross-account.html) doc